# Spring Security make an angular resource fail

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, angular-resource

I have implemented to the existing app a Spring Security module, which actually looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    //.antMatchers("/resources/**", "/").permitAll()
                    //.antMatchers("/welcome").hasRole("ADMIN") //tu mogla by byc pobrana jaka rola i te linki np tylko dla admina
                    //.anyRequest().permitAll() //reszta po zalogowaniu
                    //.antMatchers("/resources/templates/index.html").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/views/pages/signIn.html").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/views/worker/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.WORKER)
                    .antMatchers("/views/client/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/views/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/templates/index.html").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/addAdmin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/addWorker/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/assignWorkerToWash/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/header/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/info/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/reservation/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/reservationReminder/**").hasAnyRole(AuthoritiesConstants.WORKER, AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/review/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/vehicle/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/vehicle/**").hasAnyRole(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/review/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/washType/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/vehicleType/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/scripts/directives/wash/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)

                    //.antMatchers("/api/reservationreminder").permitAll()


                    //???
                    .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/templates/index.html").permitAll()
                    //.antMatchers("/api/client, /api/reservation", "/api/reservationreminder", "/api/review", "/api/user", "/api/vehicle", "/api/wash", "/api/washlocation", "/api/washtype", "/api/worker").hasAnyRole(AuthoritiesConstants.WORKER, AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT)
                    .antMatchers("/app/styles/**", "/app/js/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/build/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/views/pages/login.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/views/pages/login.html")
                    .permitAll()

    }
}
```

And the directory tree looks like:

[image]

After the implementation I got strange fails according to the `$resource` module which I use in angularJS - before the Spring Security implementation everything works fine.

The symptom of the fail is that I can't log in through login page because of `Error in resource configuration for action "query". Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET /api/reservationreminder)`.

When we go to that service I have:

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp').factory('ReservationReminderService', function($resource) {

var service = $resource('/api/reservationreminder/', {id : '@id'},
    {


    });

return service;
 });
```

And I the LoginCtrl (angular) I use the query() method which accepts array:

```
ReservationReminderService.query().$promise.then(function (res) {
            UserService.setData('reminders', res);
            UserService.setData('wasSeen', true);

            var userRoles = UserService.getRoles();
            if (userRoles.indexOf('client') > -1){
                $state.go('dashboard.myaccount');
                return;
            }

            if (userRoles.indexOf('worker') > -1){
                $state.go('dashboard.workerreservation');
                return;
            }

            $state.go('dashboard.home');
        });
```

So I really don't know why there is a fail? Maybe it is something wrong with Spring Security configuration?

The previous, very basic Spring Security configuration was like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
              .and()
}
```

And then, everything works fine.

[UPDATE]
Angular controller:

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, LoginService, $http, $state, UserService, AddUserService, $q, ReservationReminderService) {

$scope.User = {};
$scope.Error = null;

$scope.login = function () {
    $scope.Error = null;
    $http.post('auth/login', $scope.User).success(function (res, a, b) {
        UserService.setUserData(res);

        ReservationReminderService.query().$promise.then(function (res) {
            UserService.setData('reminders', res);
            UserService.setData('wasSeen', true);

            var userRoles = UserService.getRoles();
            if (userRoles.indexOf('client') > -1){
                $state.go('dashboard.myaccount');
                return;
            }

            if (userRoles.indexOf('worker') > -1){
                $state.go('dashboard.workerreservation');
                return;
            }

            $state.go('dashboard.home');
        });
    }).error(function (data) {
        // jeżeli 403 - pokaz blad
        // jezeli 5xx - alert wewnetrzny blad serwera
        if (data.status == 403)
            $scope.Error = "Błędny login lub hasło";
        else alert(data.message);
    });
    //console.log('ReservationReminderService.query();', ReservationReminderService.query())
};

$scope.signInForm = function () {
    $state.transitionTo('signIn');
}
});
```

[UPDATE 2]

```
   @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/reservationreminder")
    public class ReservationReminderController {
    @Autowired
    private ReservationReminderServiceImpl reminderService;
    @Autowired
    private WorkerServiceImpl workerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ReservationReminder>     getReservationReminderList(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Principal name = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (name.getName() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Brak sesji");
        }
        Worker workerByLogin = workerService.findWorkerByLogin(name.getName());
        List<ReservationReminder> byReservationWorkerPesel = reminderService.findByReservationWorkerPesel(workerByLogin);
        return byReservationWorkerPesel;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void insertOrUpdate(@RequestBody List<ReservationReminder> reservationReminderList) {
        for (ReservationReminder r : reservationReminderList) {
            if (r.getChecked() == true) {
                reminderService.insertOrUpdate(r);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably due to `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` can you show us your controller?

Comment: can you try a GET request from a Rest Client like Postman or Curl to /api/reservationreminder/, what do you get?

Comment: There other fails with angular, now it's `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: I think that you are not authorized properly and when you execute the Http GET request, you get an error message from Spring rather than the object you want. did you try removing @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true).

Comment: Yes I deleted them. I think that I'm properly authorized because before that changes everything works fine